# Trouble setting page number to bold

Tags: page-numbering

It should be pretty straightforward, but I couldn't figure it out so far: page numbers work for headers and in the plain style, but not in the others. Nothing I do seems to affect `\thepage`, not even `\textbf` etc.

```
\documentclass[sfheadings]{mwbk}
\usepackage{lipsum}



%\pagestyle{headings}


\makeatletter
\let\ps@opening\ps@plain
\let\ps@closing\ps@headings
\renewcommand\heading@font{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand\hf@plain{%
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{\heading@font\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
  }
\renewcommand\hf@headings{%
  \def\@oddhead{\heading@font\rightmark\hfil\thepage}%
  \let\@oddfoot\@empty
  \def\@evenhead{\heading@font\thepage\hfil\leftmark}% <<< heading@font only affects \leftmark
  \let\@evenfoot\@empty
    }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{asdf}
\lipsum[15-17]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure, but try with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: @MadyYuvi, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to redeclare `\pagestyle{headings}` after modifying it.

Also the instructions for `\ps@opening` and `\ps@closing` should be delayed at `\begin{document}`.

```latex
\documentclass[sfheadings]{mwbk}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\heading@font{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand\hf@plain{%
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{\heading@font\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}
\renewcommand\hf@headings{%
  \def\@oddhead{\heading@font\rightmark\hfil\thepage}%
  \let\@oddfoot\@empty
  \def\@evenhead{\heading@font\thepage\hfil\leftmark}%
  \let\@evenfoot\@empty
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\ps@opening\ps@plain
  \let\ps@closing\ps@headings
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}


\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\lipsum[1-10]

\section{asdf}

\lipsum[15-17]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The chapter page is on the left just for convenience (making a smaller picture).

Comment: Didn't realize that. Why should `\ps@opening` and `\ps@closing` be delayed after `\begin{document}`? The result seems to be the same.

Comment: @BlackBird I didn't investigate too deeply; I found that if you do it in the preamble, the definition of `\ps@plain` in the body doesn't change, so I tried with `\AtBeginDocument`.